# How can i use typescript to trace data flow and rename them?

Tags: typescript

In our project, there are lots of types as combination of Record<string, any>. Need to trace these keys, and rename them into short one for compressing.

Comment: Why not use any refactoring tool you have in your IDE? Like search&replace?

Comment: I'm trying to compress and mangle my code in a customed js container called "wechatMiniprogram" for production mode.